# how to map a postgres' string into a property

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I have the following code for mapping the list of Postgres' timezones, but `utcoffset` is always set to `null`. `is_dst` and `measure` is filled correctly.

```
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
        $rsm->addEntityResult('MyVendor\ContainerBundle\Entity\TimezoneMeasure', 'tz');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('tz', 'measure', 'measure');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('tz', 'utcOffset', 'utc_offset');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('tz', 'is_dst', 'isDst');

        $query = $this->em->createNativeQuery("SELECT tz.name AS measure, to_char(tz.utc_offset, 'HH24') AS utc_offset, tz.is_dst AS is_dst FROM pg_timezone_names() tz;", $rsm);
        $timeZones = $query->getResult();
```

the class has the following mapping:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class TimezoneMeasure extends Measure
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o", "o-all"})
     */
    private $utcOffset;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @Serializer\Groups({"o", "o-all"})
     */
    private $isDst;
    ...
```

I've tried "text" as well as "string". Any suggestion?